# Can I make WCF applications using Microsoft Visual C# Express 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I'd like to know if the express editions allows you to make WCF applications and what is **cut** from the Express edition in comparison from the full on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep here is a link explaning the features of the express editions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/danielfe/archive/2007/11/19/top-15-things-to-love-about-visual-studio-2008-express.aspx

> All Visual Studio Express Editions also enable you to consume data from Web services as well as support for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). Visual Web Developer Express also adding support for *creating* WCF applications.

And is supported in 2010 as well.

Comment: Ah, it allows me to CONSUME the services, but not create them?

Comment: @Sergio you should be able to create them as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en#filelist

This is a feature chart for 2008.  I can't see 2010 being much different in terms of missing features from the Express Editions.

As WCF is part of the .NET framework, I believe you can still write applications that use WCF even if the IDE (Visual Studio) doesn't provide the nice GUI and project templates to help you.